# how does s suffix in arm assembly instructions work?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am new to assembly and wanted to know how does the s suffix added to the opcode of arm assembly instructions work. I have read it is used to update the condition flags based on the result of an operation. Is there a summary of the possible ways to update the condition flags based on a result of an operation? based on what properties of the result which flag bit do I update ?.

lets take this assembly code instruction as an example
000080fa         movs r1, #0

what exactly does it do in the context of updating the condition flags?

Comment: It is advisable to add an example of what you're asking about so that people can help you better :)

Comment: there are two parts to this, first is the bit in the instruction (in arm, original thumb it is assumed) that enables or disables the update of the flags.  Then per instruction that does affect flags the arm documentation lists what happens to each flag.   So there is the instruction side of this.

Comment: the assembly language side of this is that assembly language is specific to the assembler, the tool, not the target, there can be and are in this case different, incompatible assembly languages that generate the same machine instructions.  this is the nature of the beast as the processor vendor ideally wants a document with assembly language and machine code and will make that assembly language, ideally, match an assembler it created or supports.   But as we well know with folks like gnu they, intentionally?, make incompatible assembly languages for various targets.   as in this case.

Comment: there are exceptions but most of the time yes the s means enable flags and/or with thumb that helps you get the 16 bit non-thumb2 instruction.  then what the flags do for each instruction is simply documented by arm and you just look it up.   note that for arm you really need to examine this for each individual instruction you are interested in as the flags are not always used in the same way from instruction to instruction. some instructions dont touch certain flags, and some have special cases for certain flags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the flags are updated differs by instruction.  But generally, the following happens when a flag-setting instruction is executed:

- the N flag is set if the result is negative (i.e. the sign bit is set)
- the Z flag is set if the result is zero
- the C flag is set according to the carry out of the third operand shift
- the V flag is unchanged

For instructions that shift the third operand by zero or do not have a way to encode a shift, the carry flag too remains unchanged.  For instructions that are variants of addition, the C and V flags are instead set according to the carry and overflow of the addition.

Comment: just for clarity how will the condition flags look like after this instruction here for example `cmp r0, #3` assuming r0 holds a value of 50....also assuming the condition flags state before instruction execution was N=0, Z=1, C=0, V=0

Comment: what happened when you tried this instruction on an arm processor, what flags did you see and what flags are you confused about?

Comment: i am implementing my own arm processor simulator. so I need to get the condition flags setting behavior correctly....what i settled for the state of the flags are N=0, Z=0, C=0, V=0 after the example instruction executes

Comment: @fuz: Sorry, I thought we were still talking about `movs r1, #0`.  Will delete.